# Microsoft SSRS 2016 Lookup (on dynamic dataset) and return multiple (n) columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, lookup

I have a unique Microsoft  SSRS (2016) situation:

I have this table below:

Table A (3 columns; key column:  OrderID) the main table, main dataset - **fixed dataset:**

```
OrderID Region  Store
124     FL      ORL-23
125     CA      SFO-21
126     TX      DAL-19
```

I have another table, Table B (4 columns; key column:  OrderID) in another dataset (say Lookup dataset):

```
OrderID Gratuity    DeliveryFee Surcharge
124     $2.50       $3.00       $0.75
125     $3.50       $5.50       $0.67
126     $4.75       $3.75       $0.45
```

Table B (Lookup dataset) is actually a **dynamic table**; it can have 3 columns (as shown above)  apart from OrderID, the base column; in some other cases (via parameters), it can have 4 columns (apart from OrderID), and so on - - say, **n columns apart from OrderID**, where n depends on a parameter value I choose.

I need to get the following **result set** (**Table C** with 6 columns (in this particular case, when Table B has 3 dynamic columns)), lookedup on OrderID column):

```
OrderID Region  Store   Gratuity    DeliveryFee Surcharge
124     FL      ORL-23  $2.50       $3.00       $0.75
125     CA      SFO-21  $3.50       $5.50       $0.67
126     TX      DAL-19  $4.75       $3.75       $0.45
```

Table A:         fixed 3 columns;
Table B:         n varying columns

I need to get table C in SSRS 2016; I have options such as Lookup, LookupSet, MultiLookup, etc.

Remember that Table C must have 3 (or n, where n is the number of columns in the dynamic dataset Table B) **new** columns (Gratuity, DeliveryFee, Surcharge), **not** 1 column concatenated in this way:

```
Fields!Gratuity.Value & ", " & Fields!DeliveryFee.Value & ", " &  Fields!Surcharge.Value
```

**Hence Table C can have 6 columns, 7 columns, ...i.e. (3+n) columns, since Table B has a varying number of columns, depending on a parameter chosen.**

How can I achieve this? Or should I try some options such as SubReport, or something?

Due to some business logic, I cannot use JOIN; table A- here I have simplified (actually Table A has many more columns with a lot of calculations such as SUM, DISTINCT COUNT, etc).  It has some aggregated calculations.

Comment: This seems like a pretty straight forward query to add. Perhaps you can add the query from the second dataset (Table B) into your first dataset (Table A) and `JOIN` on OrderID.

Comment: If you can't **JOIN** the tables in the query, can't you use a separate **LOOKUP** for each value (Gratuity, Delivery, Surcharge)? `=Lookup(Fields!OrderID.Value, Fields!OrderID.Value,  Fields!Gratuity.Value, "TableB")`

Comment: Or you can join the dataset in xsd file.

Comment: Added some extra comments ; please see now

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer  ok thanks for the advice. did know know that, will refrain from using 'ASAP'  or words like that

Comment: @SAm  Can you provide some details how to do that ?  I have added extra information about this SSRS 'puzzle'

Comment: @Hannover Fist   the problem is TableB (lookup dataset) is dynamic, it has a varying number of columns on its own (this varying number depends on a parameter value chosen); I have added extra information, you can see.

Comment: @user3812887 is it possible to use derived tables on top of your aggregatedTables? I couldn't find a way to join 2 existing dataTableAdapters into a new set in the xsd file. Using VS2012.

Comment: TableA is huge with multiple groups, and aggregated columns; that is the main reason why I cannot JOIN TableA and TableB via OrderID; TableA is actually a huge query in itself. Coming to TableB, this is actually a PIVOT of another table.  I do not think it is possible to develop a Derived Table on TableA;

Comment: The reason why I cannot use a JOIN is because, the base table for TableB (which is the PIVOT of the base table), was designed incorrectly with repetitive grouping, violating 1NF (first normal form)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in your query so it is one dataset in SSRS.

```
SELECT
    a.OrderID
    ,a.Region
    ,a.Store
    ,b.Gratuity
    ,b.DeliveryFee
    ,b.Surcharge
FROM TableA A
JOIN TableB B ON
    a.OrderID = b.OrderID
```